# Share Link of UWP App in Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP app published in Microsoft/Windows Store, and I want add a button "Share app" in my uwp app. But I want only share the link of my uwp app in Microsoft Store. 
I want to do the same as the "Share" button on the Microsoft Store on the application page.
[image: Share Button in Microsoft Store]

How do I do that?

Comment: I am so confused, you want to share your app while you are in app?

Comment: @maccettura and want share link of my app in Microsoft Store. For example: the user is in my application, and click on share button. Share UI appears, and user click on Facebook (for example), and share link (Microsoft Store) of my app on his facebook

Comment: If you find the answer below to be complete, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `DataTransferManager` to display a standard *Share* dialog and `SetWebLink` method of `DataRequest.Data` property to link to your app:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DataTransferManager dataTransferManager;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataTransferManager_DataRequested;
    }

    private void DataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataRequest request = args.Request;

        request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share the App";
        request.Data.Properties.Description = "This App in Windows Store";
        request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/netflix/9wzdncrfj3tj"));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
    }
}
```